# OracleResultSet class in ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc6.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

I have used **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet** class in my program from **ojdbc14.jar**. After that, i have upgraded Oracle 10g to 11g and from now on wards, i am using **ojdbc6.jar**.

With this new jar file, it is giving me the compilation error **"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet is not visible"**. I have extracted the class files using 
"jar xf xxx.jar" from both the jar files and took the class files for OracleResultSet class and decompiled and got the Java code. I have observed that OracleResultSet is a public class in ojdbc14.jar but there is no access modifier in ojdbc6.jar which is restricting me to use "OracleResultSet" class.

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Can't you just use the `java.sql.ResultSet` interface? In general it is not advisable to use the JDBC interface instead of the concrete implementations of a driver.

Comment: have a try oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet, it is public interface.

Comment: @TedShaw: Will it make any difference using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet and oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet. Actually your suggestion worked for me

Comment: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet implements the oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet interface, program to interface not concrete class

Answer (score 5):

I changed the import from oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet; to oracle.jdbc.*; and the error is gone.
I have again changed the import from oracle.jdbc.*; to oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet and saved. It now worked without any compilation errors.

Comment: Worked for me going from ojdbc 1.6 to 8.  Just had to replace the broken import with oracle.jdbc.* then save all, no other steps required for me.

Comment: For me works `import oracle.jdbc.*;` thanks

Answer (score -1):

use the `import line(import oracle.jdbc.*;)` and then it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure what sorcery is that, but I'm pretty sure just `import oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet` should be enough. I got here with the same problem on another class. It seems they moved some things on ojdbc6